# Как правильно загрузить фото в группу VK API

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, веб-программирование

Изучаю API VK, поставил задачу реализовать загрузку фото в альбом группы ВК, в которую есть права загружать фотографии.

Получение токена, запрос групп, альбомов с возможностью загрузки изображений - процесс пройден. Сейчас застрял непосредственно на самой загрузке. При отправке запроса получаю ошибку

> 100: One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid:
>   photos_list is invalid.

Оно и понятно, т.к. сервер после загрузки фото возвращает что-то вроде:

> [server] => 637125 [photos_list] => [] [aid] => 123456 [hash] => 4fc82033a7c5c8eed3021ff289775fec [gid] => 123456

Загружаю сл. образом:

```
public static function uploadImages($files, $group_id, $album_id)
{

    //Получаем сервер для загрузки изображения
    $params = array(
        'group_id'  =>   $group_id,
        'album_id'  =>   $album_id
        );
    $api_res = self::queryApi("photos.getUploadServer", $params);

    try
    {
        if($api_res)
        {
            $server = $api_res->upload_url;
            $post = array();

            for ($i=0; $i < count($files); $i++) 
            {
                $query = self::$connection->query('SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE `id` = '.$files[$i]);
                while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    if(!empty($row['image'])){
                        if(file_exists(config::$full_path.'images/'.$row['image'])){
                            $img = $row['image'];
                        }else{
                            $img = 'no-image.jpg';
                        }
                    }else{
                        $img = 'no-image.jpg'; 
                    }

                    $post[] = array('file'.$i+1 => '@'.config::$full_path.'images/'.$img);
                }
            }


            if($ch = curl_init($server))
            {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8'));
                $json = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
                curl_close($ch);

                $params = array(
                        'server'    =>  $json->server,
                        'photos_list'   =>  stripslashes($json->photos_list),
                        'album_id'  =>  $album_id,
                        'hash'  =>  $json->hash,
                        'gid'   =>  $group_id
                    );

                $photo_save = self::queryApi('photos.save', $params);
        //////////////
                print_r($json);
        //////////////
                if($photo_save)
                {
                    return $photo_save;
                }
                else throw new Exception("При сохранении фотографий в альбом произошла ошибка.", 1);
            }
            else throw new Exception("Ошибка инициализации cURL", 1);
        }
        else throw new Exception("При обращении к API photos.getUploadServer произошла ошибка.", 1);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
}
```

На вход послупает ID файлов в БД, группы и альбома. Формируется массив fileN => @FILE_PATH
и отправляется на полученный адрес сервера.

Запрос к API выглядит сл. обазом:

```
public static function queryApi($api, $params = null, $type = 0)
    {
        if($type == 0)
        {
            $server = 'https://api.vk.com/method/';
        }else{
            $server = 'https://oauth.vk.com/';
        }

        $params['access_token'] = $_SESSION['vk']['access_token'];
        $params['v'] = config::$vk_api['ver'];

        $postparams = http_build_query($params);

        try{
            if($curl = curl_init()) 
            {
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $server.$api);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postparams);
                $result = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
                curl_close($curl);

                if(isset($result->error))
                {
                    if($type == 0)
                    {
                        $error_msg = "При запросе к VK API возникла ошибка. ERROR CODE: ".$result->error->error_code."; MESSAGE: ".$result->error->error_msg;
                    }else{
                        $error_msg = "При попытке авторизации произошла ошибка. ERROR: ".$result->error."; DESCRIPTION: ".$result->error_description;
                    }

                    throw new Exception($error_msg, 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    return $result;                        
                }

            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Ошибка инициализации модуля cURL.", 1);
            }
        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Но в результате работы получаю пустой photos_list

Переменная  **$full_path = 'D:/OpenServer/domains/localhost/';**

Прошу помочь разобраться и направить в нужный мануал ) Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решил заменой в первой функции строки:

```
 $post[] = array('file'.$i+1 => '@'.config::$full_path.'images/'.$img);
```

на

```
 $post['file'.$i+1] = new CURLFile(config::$full_path.'images/'.$img);
```

Документация [ТУТ](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php)

Работает с версии PHP 5.6+